# How to get details of single products of a grouped product in observer

Tags: product, grouped-products, event-observer

I wrote

```
    public function catalogProductTypePrepare($observer)
     {
    $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    $productid = $product->getId();
    $buyRequest = $observer->getEvent()->getBuyRequest();
    $productqtty = $buyRequest->getQty();
```

it returns the last product of the grouped product I want to get each one of the single product of the grouped product

Answer (score 2):

Try below code :

```
public function catalogProductTypePrepare($observer)
    {
        $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        if($product->getTypeId() == 'grouped') // check if the product is grouped product
        {
            $associatedProducts = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProducts($product);
            // get all simple products details through $associatedProducts
        }
    }
```

Comment: no it is not working because $product returns the last one of the single product and not the grouped product